# How do you pass a cell value from a table to a combobox?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, range

I'm trying to build a form in Excel VBA. I've got the form built, but I want the user to be able to edit the data in the form. I want a user to to able to enter a parameter, and then the form will search the table to see if the parameter exists. If it does, then the form will populate with the data in that row.

I have no idea why this code works, but I can't seem to get the data in the cell out. I can see, from a watch, that the correct cell is being selected. But the cell will not assign to my variable, or to the combo box. Here's what I've got so far!

```
Public Function LoadFormEdit(Row As Integer)
Dim rng As Range
Dim RowNum As Integer
RowNum = Row
Dim lookupValue As String
'Set the range to be the table we want to work with
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyWorksheet").Range("MyDataTable")

Dim ColOffset As Integer
ColOffset = rng.Column - 1

'Add the selections to the ComboBox, and make visible
Me.MyComboBox.Visible = True
lookupValue = rng.Cells(RowNum, 6).Text
Me.MyComboBox.value = lookupValue
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In true Stack Overflow fashion, I figured this out after I posted it.

The problem was that I wasn't correctly accounting for the fact that my table isn't located at 1,1 in the worksheet. Therefore, the following code fixed things:

```
Public Function LoadFormEdit(Row As Integer)
Dim rng As Range
Dim RowNum As Integer
Dim RowOffset As Integer
Dim lookupValue As String

'Set the range to be the table we want to work with
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MyDataSheet").Range("MyDataTable")
RowOffset = rng.Row - 1
RowNum = Row - RowOffset


'Add the selections to the ComboBox, and make visible
Me.MyComboBox.Visible = True
lookupValue = rng.Cells(RowNum, 5).value
Me.MyComboBox.value = lookupValue
```